# How can I make a list that will contain all elements that have given xpath?

Tags: java, android, testing, appium, mobile-application

I try to learn how to work with native Android application using Appium and Java.

I have a structure:

> Class B contains: 
>       class A: element_1 
>       class A: element_2

I need to get all element that have class B and put them into a list.

How do I do list of child elements in Java using Appium for Android native application?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can put all the elements in the list:

```
List<WebElement> el = driver.findElementsByClassName("classB");
```

Comment: Thanks but it is right to use "WebElement" despite "MobileElement"? What is the difference?

Comment: @Fanthom : you can use either, keeping in mind that `MobileElement` is extended from `WebElement`